# Java GPA CALC issue

Tags: java

My totals will not update. Every time I execute the code the gpa displays 0.0. I added the "gp" to see if the "grade points would update when the user information was entered but it will not. Any help would be great! I looked at the other issues and could not seem to solve mine!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GUITestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
        double credits;
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name:");
        student.setName(name);
        credits = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the credits:"));
        student.setCredits(credits);

        String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your grade:");
        student.setGrade(grade);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, student.displayStudentInformation());           
    } 
}

public class StudentInfo {
        private String  name;
        private double  totalGradePoints;
        private double  credits;
        private String  grade;
        private double  gpa;

        public StudentInfo(){
            setGrade(null);
            setCredits(0);
            setGradePoints(0);
        }
        public StudentInfo(double credits, double totalGradePoints, String grade){
            setGrade(grade);
            setCredits(credits);
            setGradePoints(totalGradePoints);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }
        public void setGrade(String grade) {
            this.grade = grade;
        }
        public double getCredits() {
            return credits;
        }
        public void setCredits(double credits) {
            this.credits = credits;
        }

        public double getGradePoints() {
            return totalGradePoints;
        }
        public void setGradePoints(double totalGradePoints) {
            this.totalGradePoints = totalGradePoints;
        }

        public double getGpa() {
            return gpa;
        }
        public void setGpa(double gpa) {
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }

        public double addClass(double totalGradePoints, String grade){
        double gradePoints = 0;
        if(grade.equals("A")){
            gradePoints = 4.0;
        }else if(grade.equals("B")){
            gradePoints = 3.0;
        } else if(grade.equals("C")){
            gradePoints = 2.0;
        } else if(grade.equals("D")){
            gradePoints = 1.0;}
        totalGradePoints = (totalGradePoints +gradePoints);

        return getGradePoints();
        }

        public double getGPA(){
            this.setGpa(this.getCredits() / this.getGradePoints());
            return this.getGpa();
        }

        public String displayStudentInformation(){
            String output = "";

            output = output + "Name: " + this.getName() + "\n";
            output = output + "Total Credits: " + this.getCredits() + "\n";
            output = output + "Your grade is: " + this.getGrade() + "\n";
            output = output + "Your GPA is: " + this.getGpa() +  "\n";
            output = output + "Press any key to continue!" + "\n";
            output = output + "gp" + totalGradePoints + "\n";

            return output;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your this.getGradePoints(). it is not a getter of a value and you do not set the value inside the function for the same object instance of your student from StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
You have to set all your setter variables on that object 'student' you created.

Try this:

```
package guitestclient;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GUITestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
        double credits;
        double gradePoints = 0;
        double gradePointsTot = 0;
        double gpa = 0;
        int classCount = 0;


        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name:");
        student.setName(name);
      do{
        credits = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the credits:"));
        student.setCredits(credits);

        String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your grade:");
        student.setGrade(grade);

        //calculates gpa value for grade
        gradePoints = StudentInfo.addClass(gradePoints, grade);
        gradePointsTot += gradePoints;
        classCount++;
     } while (classCount < 5);    

        //after loop
        student.setGradePoints(gradePointsTot);
        gpa = StudentInfo.getGPA(credits, gpa, classCount);
        student.setGpa(gpa);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, student.displayStudentInformation());           
    } 
}

class StudentInfo {
        private String  name;
        private double  totalGradePoints;
        private double  credits;
        private String  grade;
        private double  gpa;

        public StudentInfo(){
            setGrade(null);
            setCredits(0);
            setGradePoints(0);
        }
        public StudentInfo(double credits, double totalGradePoints, String grade){
            setGrade(grade);
            setCredits(credits);
            setGradePoints(totalGradePoints);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }
        public void setGrade(String grade) {
            this.grade = grade;
        }
        public double getCredits() {
            return credits;
        }
        public void setCredits(double credits) {
            this.credits = credits;
        }

        public double getGradePoints() {
            return totalGradePoints;
        }
        public void setGradePoints(double totalGradePoints) {
            this.totalGradePoints = totalGradePoints;
        }

        public double getGpa() {
            return gpa;
        }
        public void setGpa(double gpa) {
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }

        public static double addClass(double totalGradePoints, String grade){
        double gradePoints = 0;
        if(grade.equals("A")){
            gradePoints = 4.0;
        }else if(grade.equals("B")){
            gradePoints = 3.0;
        } else if(grade.equals("C")){
            gradePoints = 2.0;
        } else if(grade.equals("D")){
            gradePoints = 1.0;}
        totalGradePoints = (totalGradePoints +gradePoints);

        return totalGradePoints;
        }

        public static double getGPA(double totalGradePoints, double credits, double gpa){
            gpa = (credits * totalGradePoints)/ credits;
            return gpa;
        }


        public String displayStudentInformation(){
            String output = "";

            output = output + "Name: " + this.getName() + "\n";
            output = output + "Total Credits: " + this.getCredits() + "\n";
            output = output + "Your grade is: " + this.getGrade() + "\n";
            output = output + "Your GPA is: " + this.getGpa() +  "\n";
            output = output + "Press any key to continue!" + "\n";
            output = output + "gp" + this.getGradePoints() + "\n";

            return output;z
        }
}
```

Comment: Not only do I want to hug you right now, I want to take a running start, jump up, wrap my legs around you and hug you until it gets weird.

Comment: it was not 100% correct, but it got me where I needed. Here is the only correction:
        public static double getGPA(double totalGradePoints, double credits, double gpa){
            
            gpa = (credits * totalGradePoints)/ credits;
            return gpa;
        }

Comment: You should also check the accepted answer if it was most helpful in finding a solution for your question :)

Comment: I would do that if I knew where it were located.  You wouldn't happen to know how to add an accumulator for totaling up the variables "credits" and "totalGradePoints" inside a do while loop would you?

Comment: It is right underneath the upvote/downvote arrows on the left of the answer

Comment: I will edit answer with what I think you mean by accumulator and we can go from there

Comment: I will just post it in a new thread. It will not let me edit!?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public double addClass(double totalGradePoints, String grade){
    double gradePoints = 0;
    if(grade.equals("A")){
        gradePoints = 4.0;
    }else if(grade.equals("B")){
        gradePoints = 3.0;
    } else if(grade.equals("C")){
        gradePoints = 2.0;
    } else if(grade.equals("D")){
        gradePoints = 1.0;}

    totalGradePoints = (totalGradePoints +gradePoints);
}
```

The problem is in the final statement of `addClass`.  Java is *pass-by-value*, which means that the `totalGradePoints` visible here is a local variable, within the `addClass` method, containing a ***copy*** of whatever value you passed when calling `addClass`.  Any updates you make to that value affect only the local copy, not the original variable.

The method signature doesn't need a `totalGradePoints` parameter.  It should be

```
public double addClass(String grade) {
    ...
```

and you need to add the local `gradePoints` to the class' member variable `totalGradePoints`.

Comment: I am not sure I would understand what that would look like? A get/set for "gradePoints?"

Answer (score -1):

In your addClass method, you have totalGradePoints as a local variable.

```
public double addClass(double totalGradePoints, String grade)
```

You should use the global variable totalGradePoints instead of a local one. So remove that variable so the method looks like

```
public double addClass(String grade)
```

But I do not see anywhere that you call the addClass method.

Comment: yeah, it is going to be a loop for multiple class/grade entries, but I wanted to make sure I could get one down first. I followed your instructions and they will still not update according to the user inputs.